# Can I get user email using Instagram API login?

Tags: api, authentication, instagram

I tried to use Instagram oauth API login but I can't get User email where as I can get profile picture, user url, comments and all.

So can anyone tell me if there is any option to get user email?

Here is snippet for you:

```
print_r($result->data); exit;
    // display all user likes
    foreach ($result->data as $media) {
        $content = "<li>";

        // output media
        if ($media->type === 'video') {
            // video
            $poster = $media->images->low_resolution->url;
            $source = $media->videos->standard_resolution->url;
            $content .= "<video class=\"media video-js vjs-default-skin\" width=\"250\" height=\"250\" poster=\"{$poster}\"
                       data-setup='{\"controls\":true, \"preload\": \"auto\"}'>
                         <source src=\"{$source}\" type=\"video/mp4\" />
                       </video>";
        } else {
            // image
            $image = $media->images->low_resolution->url;
            $content .= "<img class=\"media\" src=\"{$image}\"/>";
        }

        // create meta section
        $avatar = $media->user->profile_picture;
        $username = $media->user->username;
        $comment = $media->caption->text;

        $content .= "<div class=\"content\">
                       <div class=\"avatar\" style=\"background-image: url({$avatar})\"></div>
                       <p>{$username}</p>
                       <div class=\"comment\">{$comment}</div>
                     </div>";
```

Here I can get avatar,username and comment. But I need email to be fetched.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is possible to get email and phone, but not everyone can do it. I saw some apps those took my email and auto-enter it in text box

Answer (score 50):

The API don't return the user email. This is an example of all the fields that you can get: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users

Comment: Is there no other way to get user's email?

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal Even though it is almost 6 years later, there's still no way to get the user's email. The only reliable way seems to be checking the user's profile on the mobile app (yes, that email won't even show on the desktop).